# Terminating timed out worker of puma in ebs on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, server, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

Running rails app in elastic-beanstalk for quite long time so far I didn't face this issue. My server keeps on restarting with logs as

```
[4412] ! Terminating timed out worker: 8646
[4412] ! Out-of-sync worker list, no 8646 worker
[4412] ! Out-of-sync worker list, no 8646 worker
```

In ebs log, I am getting

> Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning. 50.0 % of the requests to the ELB are failing with HTTP 5xx. Insufficient request rate (3.0 requests/min) to determine application health (5 minutes ago). 1 out of 1 instances are impacted. See instance health for details.

My instance ran in t2.medium(CPU core 2), is this because of heavy load on the server? Do I need to upgrade my instance? I am totally stuck.

FYI: I included puma only by having in gemfile, as rails 4.+ can handle.

Suggest me your opinion on this. Thanks.

Comment: did you solve this problem? I got same problem too

Comment: Look through the entirety of your `/var/log/eb-activity.log` file from the last deploy and see if there are other errors.  I was having this issue and thought it was due to Puma since the deploy seemed to complete successfully, but I had some asset compiling issues and missing environment variables that were actually the real problem.